# working with var variable in method "AsEnumerable" throwing Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, visual-studio-2012

Hi everyone I got an Error when I run my Code, the Error Is

"Specified cast is not valid."

and this is my Code

```
       var result = dst.Tables["SalesInAccpac"].AsEnumerable()
                         .GroupBy(row => new
                         {
                             Mon = row.Field<int>("Mon"),
                             Region = row.Field<string>("Region"),
                             Str = row.Field<string>("Str"),
                             RcptDate = row.Field<DateTime>("RcptDate")
                         }).Select(x => new
                                  {
                                      Mon = x.Key.Mon,
                                      Region = x.Key.Region,
                                      Str = x.Key.Str,
                                      RcptDate = x.Key.RcptDate,
                                      TotalCost = x.Sum(z => z.Field<double>("TotalCost")),
                                      TotalRound = x.Sum(z => z.Field<double>("TotalRound"))
                                  });



        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            string sos = item.Mon.ToString();
            string TotalCost = item.TotalCost.ToString();
        }
```

please can any one help me ?

Comment: Watch out for `DBNull`, otherwise check the types you have are right (e.g. `TotalCost` is actually a `double`).

Comment: The `var` and the `AsEnumerable()` are irrelevant. Some column does not contain the value you expect. Set breakpoints, inspect your variables.